# How do I call a function from a different file to the main?

Tags: python

So I am trying to read this folder that has pictures/gifs of all 52 cards of the deck. I am reading the file in my readFile function which is my card class. I want those pictures to be added to a list called deck. I want make sure thats it is being added to deck. To test this I  trying to call it in the main.

#card.py

```py
import os

class Card:
    def __init__(self, deckFile):
        self._deckFile = deckFile
        self.readFile()

    def readFile(self, deckFile):
        dirName = os.getcwd()
        contents = os.listdir()
        for card in contents:
            if os.path.isdir(card):
                for card2 in os.listdir(card):
                    entry = os.path.join(card, card2)
                    if os.path.isfile(entry) and card2.endswith(".gif"):
                        print(os.path.join(dirName, entry))
            elif card.endswith(".gif"):
                print(os.path.join(dirName, card))
```

#main.py

```
from Card import readFile

def main():
        print(readFile())

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: That isn't how it works.  ```readFile``` is a method within the ```Card``` class.  You need to instantiate ```Card``` and then use ```readFile```.  Anyway, even assuming what you wrote 'works', you're still missing a parameter for ```readFile```

Comment: if you want to use the a function inside the class without create a object from it you should declare that function as **static function** :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to import the `Card` class from `card.py`.

```
from card import Card
```

Then create a `Card` object, providing a value for the `deckFile` argument. Then you'd call `readFile` on `a_card`, apparently providing another `deckFile` argument to that call.

E.g.

```
a_card = Card(whatever_a_deck_file_is)
a_card.readFile(another_of_whatever_a_deck_file_is)
```

Beware printing the result of `readFile`. As shown, `readFile` prints a bunch of stuff but doesn't *return* anything, so it returns `None`. If you print that you'll just get an extra `None` printed to your screen.

One wonders if `readFile` even needs that argument, or if it should just use `self._deckFile`.

Comment: When you say create a Card object, would that be like self._card = deckfile and then do self.readFile(deckFile) in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `readFile` function is inside a class, you'll need to import the class .

```
from card import Card
```

Then, you can choose to either create an instance of the class or call the function directly.

**Create an instance and call the function:**

```
card = Card(your argument)
card.readFile(your argument)
```

**Call the function directly:**

```
Card(your argument).readFile(your argument)
```

Please note that when you call the function directly, it will not create an instance of the class.

Also, the `readFile` function already has a `print` function inside. So you don't need to wrap another `print` function around the `readFile` function. If you wanted to do that, you would need to `return` something from the `readFile` function.